# Hacker Experience New missions not generated

Tags: hacker-experience

So I just completed the tutorial and I waited 14 min for a new mission like it said but it never came. Now it just says random amounts when I come back. Like 3 min or 5 min but it never actually gives one to me! Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: @GiantTree you should add this as an answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: @Warface I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually have companies in your [database](https://hackerexperience.com/list).
Start by hacking the companies on the [First Whois](https://hackerexperience.com/internet?ip=1.2.3.4) site (Cracker lvl 1.4+ is enough) and check back every once in a while to see if you are eligible for a mission.
For more information see http://wiki.hackerexperience.com/en:missions